# Haskell dictionary functionality with a closure

Tags: function, dictionary, haskell, closures

If i have a two data types `type VarName = String` and `type E = VarName -> Maybe Integer`where `E` represent some enviroment. Rather than using a map I would like to simulate a map with a closure somehow. I.e the enviroment would be initialized with something like
`initE = \_v -> Nothing` I would like to have a function that extends this initial enviroment like

`extendE :: VarName -> Integer -> E -> E`

Then if i call `extendE "x" 42 initE` to update the enviroment and contain `x` that is bounded to the value 42 now. How could i go about implementing the extendE function?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your new environment will be a wrapper around both the new key/value pair and the old environment. Lookup up a key in an environment is a two-step process:

1. If the given key matches the wrapped key, return the wrapped value.
2. Otherwise, apply the old environment to the given key.

I'll leave it as an exercise to fill in the body.

```
extendE :: VarName -> Integer -> E -> E
extendE newkey newvalue env = \key -> ...
```

In the body of the return value, you can compare `key` with `newkey`, which will tell you whether you want to return `Just newvalue` or `env key`.

Answer (score 0):

So you want

```
type VarName = String
type E = VarName -> Maybe Integer

initE v = Nothing

extendE :: VarName -> Integer -> E -> E
extendE "x" 42 initE "x" = Just 42    -- same "x"
extendE "x" 42 initE  v  = Nothing    -- something else
```

and it just works as it is,

> ```
> GHCi> extendE "x" 42 initE "x" 
> Just 42
> GHCi> extendE "x" 42 initE "v" 
> Nothing 
> GHCi>
> ```

Of course you'd probably want to generalize it a *little* bit,

```
extendE name theAnswer initE v 
             | v == name = Just ....
             | otherwise = ....
```

and it works as well, after we fill the blanks. In fact, that is the definition you wanted.

I've left one crucial bit for you to complete there, namely, how to generalize that `Nothing` in this context, *making use* of the relevant bits available to us (that is to say, function parameters). Can we produce `Nothing` by applying what to what?

(I've also played a little trick on you with the naming of one of the parameters... Hope you've noticed.)